# How to obfuscate android library without compilation

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, jitpack

I have an android library hosted on jitpack, but due to its dependencies requirements it is not built to and AAR file. It just a basic project that you can pull the methods from.

I want to hide the names for the classes, methods, and variables within the project itself without compilation. I understand that I could minify it in the gradle but that would only work once the project is built into and apk or bundle.

Is there a way to post process the code to have the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer I was looking for. Jitpack pre-builds the project after you commit changes. In this compilation process it does take the minification in the gradle and proguard rules into account. Even though I don't distribute an AAR or Jar file, the code still gets hidden in the same way.

In conclusion, Just set up the minification and proguard rules as your normally would and Jitpack will handle the rest.